# Поиск слов в файле на русском

Tags: python

Есть файл уров.txt, в котором записаны некоторые слова на русском. Необходимо вывести кол-во определенных слов. Проблема в том, что почему-то русские слова в файле считает как 0, т.е вообще не ищет их. Если делать это с английскими то все нормально. В чем проблема. Python 3.8.5

```
f=open('уров.txt', encoding='utf-8')
f.readlines()
lec = pract = lab = 0
for s in f:
i=s.find('лекц')
if i > -1:
    lec += 1
else:
    i=s.find('практ.')
    if i > -1:
        pract += 1
    else:
        i=s.find('лаб.')
        if i > -1:
            lab += 1
    print('Лекций:', lec)
    print('Практических:', pract)
    print('Лабораторных:', lab)
    f.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что, сделать скриншот и вставить его быстрее и проще, чем просто скопипастить код, как того требуют правила?

Comment: f=open('уров.txt', encoding='utf-8')
f.readlines()
lec = pract = lab = 0
for s in f:
    i=s.find('лекц')
    if i > -1:
        lec += 1
    else:
        i=s.find('практ.')
        if i > -1:
            pract += 1
        else:
            i=s.find('лаб.')
            if i > -1:
                lab += 1
print('Лекций:', lec)
print('Практических:', pract)
print('Лабораторных:', lab)
f.close()

Comment: какая кодировка файла то?

Comment: utf-8 вроде как

Answer (score 2, accepted):

после `f.readlines()` содержимое `f` исчезло и цикл `for` ничего не делает.

у строк есть метод `count`, поэтому можно обойтись без циклов

также лучше использовать конструкцию `with`

```
with open('уров.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()
    lec = text.count("лекц")
    ...
```